# Does VBA have a Hash_HMAC

Tags: excel, vba, sha512

Hi I am trying to Encrypt a string to invoke a web service from VBA. I need to do the following function in VBA and i have example code in PHP. Here is the PHP code. Does anyone know how to do this in VBA?

```
$binaryHash = hash_hmac('sha512', $url.$timestamp, $ws_session_array["sharedSecret"], true);
$hash = base64_encode($binaryHash);
```

Comment: http://www.karenware.com/powertools/pthasher.asp

Comment: @Tim Williams, that's an interesting site in general, thanks.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068548/base64-hmac-sha1-string-in-vba

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
Public Function Base64_HMACSHA1(ByVal sTextToHash As String, ByVal sSharedSecretKey As String)

    Dim asc As Object, enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

    TextToHash = asc.Getbytes_4(sTextToHash)
    SharedSecretKey = asc.Getbytes_4(sSharedSecretKey)
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey

    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    Base64_HMACSHA1 = EncodeBase64(bytes)
    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing

End Function

Private Function EncodeBase64(ByRef arrData() As Byte) As String

    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    ' byte array to base64
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Oh, and also it should be "System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512"

Comment: Could someone explain what `CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")` does? And it looks like `ComputeHash_2` is a munged name used because VBA can't overload functions. Is there some well-documented, systematic way of using .NET classes from VBA that this code is tapping into?