# System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 is Com visible. How should I call ComputeHash?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to create an HMAC SHA1 signature of some text in Microsoft Access

The .net object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 is com visible, so I thought I could use that.

I can create the object and set the key, but when I come to call the compute function to get the hash, I am getting the error run time error 5 "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"

```
Public Function sign(Key As String, Message As String)
    Dim asc, enc
    Dim MessageBytes() As bytes, HashBytes() As bytes
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")
    enc.Key = asc.GetBytes_4(Key)
    MessageBytes = asc.GetBytes_4(Message)
    HashBytes = enc.ComputeHash(MessageBytes)
    sign = EncodeBase64(HashBytes)
    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing
End Function
```

I copied the Encoding bit from the web and I note there that GetBytes has transmuted into GetBytes_4.  Is this name mangling? and do I need to do something similar to ComputeHash? and if so what (I tried _n where n = 1 to 6 to no avail).

If not What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found an answer, see below, but I haven't found any good explanation of how to use name mangling.  That would still be useful to know

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in this question

[Base64 HMAC SHA1 String in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068548/base64-hmac-sha1-string-in-vba)

I thought I had tried enc.ComputeHash_2, but maybe I didn't because it seems to work

Comment: Did you ever find out if there is a good way to lookup the right number to use for the _# suffix?

Comment: @ncovox - no sorry.  I can't remember why I asked this question and which bit of code it was for