# Is there a way to canonicalize XML using VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, xml-signature, canonicalization

I am using VBA to generate a digital signature for an XML document. Is there a transform class (part of "System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Transform", I'd guess) that I can tap into through VBA that will perform canonicalization automatically? How would I set that up? Or would I have to change the XML by hand?

I believe this was asked as a part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897645/creating-sha1-hash-and-xml-canonicalization-in-access-vba) question but that part was never answered.