# HMAC-SHA1 URL encryption in VBA produces incorrect output

Tags: python, .net, vba, encryption, hmacsha1

For Google Maps Business API queries I need to digitally sign every query using HMAC-SHA1. We use an Excel file with VBA macro to send the queries and parse the output, so I would like to create the signature in VBA. I found this question + answer: [Base64 HMAC SHA1 String in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068548/base64-hmac-sha1-string-in-vba)

However, the string signature by this code is not valid when the query is sent to the Google API.


Google provides a few sample scripts. I tested the [Python sample script](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth#signature_examples) with identical input that I used to test the VBA-code above, and the Python code *did* return a valid signature. So it seems the provided VBA code does not construct a proper HMAC-SHA1 signature, but I can't find the problem (I have no experience with encryption, and only basic VBA knowledge).


I created a HMAC-SHA1 key for testing purposes: `1412SxPev45oMMRQSXazwQp789yM=`

When run with "`abc`" as the string input I get the following returns:

VBA code: `Fsu0z3i6Ma5HCrP3eXucrdssJLc=`

Python code: `IFxkS7B_ePtZrvU8sGmiaipTHio=`


Does anyone have any idea how to compute a correct HMAC-SHA1 in VBA which equals the Python output?

**Edit 03/04/2014:**
Per Alex K.'s suggestion, I made sure to decode SharedSecretKey to Base64, using code from [http://thydzik.com](http://thydzik.com/vb6vba-functions-to-convert-binary-string-to-base64-string/). I added the function `DecodeBase64` to the VBA code below.
Since this output was correct, but not yet URL-safe (so not identical to the Python output), I used the VBA `Replace()` function to replace `+` with `-` and `/` with `_`
These solutions together produce the correct output, which is accepted by the Google servers.

**VBA script used:**

```
Public Function Base64_HMACSHA1(ByVal sTextToHash As String, ByVal sSharedSecretKey As String)

Dim asc As Object, enc As Object
Dim TextToHash() As Byte
Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

TextToHash = asc.Getbytes_4(sTextToHash)
SharedSecretKey = asc.Getbytes_4(sSharedSecretKey)
enc.Key = SharedSecretKey

Dim bytes() As Byte
bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
Base64_HMACSHA1 = EncodeBase64(bytes)
Set asc = Nothing
Set enc = Nothing

End Function

Private Function EncodeBase64(ByRef arrData() As Byte) As String

Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

' byte array to base64
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text

Set objNode = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing

End Function
```

**Added code to decode in Base64:**

```
Private Function decodeBase64(ByVal strData As String) As Byte()
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.Text = strData
decodeBase64 = objNode.nodeTypedValue


Set objNode = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

**Python script used:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf8

import sys
import hashlib
import urllib
import hmac
import base64
import urlparse

print("")
print("URL Signer 1.0")
print("")

# Convert the URL string to a URL, which we can parse
# using the urlparse() function into path and query
# Note that this URL should already be URL-encoded
url = urlparse.urlparse("YOUR_URL_TO_SIGN")

privateKey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"

# We only need to sign the path+query part of the string
urlToSign = url.path + "?" + url.query

# Decode the private key into its binary format
decodedKey = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(privateKey)

# Create a signature using the private key and the URL-encoded
# string using HMAC SHA1. This signature will be binary.
signature = hmac.new(decodedKey, urlToSign, hashlib.sha1)

# Encode the binary signature into base64 for use within a URL
encodedSignature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature.digest())
originalUrl = url.scheme + "://" + url.netloc + url.path + "?" + url.query
print("Full URL: " + originalUrl + "&signature=" + encodedSignature)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you acquire the key from the input string:

```
SharedSecretKey = asc.Getbytes_4(sSharedSecretKey)
```

But here you acquire if from Base64 decoding the input string:

```
decodedKey = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(privateKey)
```

.Net's `Getbytes` will not Base64 decode so the inputs are very different.

If you decode `SharedSecretKey` to a byte array you will get the correct output:

```
IFxkS7B/ePtZrvU8sGmiaipTHio=
```

Although note the different Base64 re-encode semantics due to `urlsafe_b64encode`.

(If you decode in .net via `Converter` you will need to lose the trailing padding `=` from the key)