# Excel formula-based function for SHA256 / SHA512 hashing without VBA or macros

Tags: excel, hash, excel-formula, sha256, sha512

It's the year 2017 and anybody who needs to use hashes should avoid 'broken' ones such as MD5, if security is important. Has anybody found or created a way to do more secure SHA256 or SHA512 hashing in Excel, without using VBA or macros?

A spectacular example of this being done before was over 3½ years ago with MD5 (as seen in this SO: [MD5 Hash function in excel without using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15201297/3598766)).

Reason for avoiding VBA/Macros: Compatibility with mobile devices, such as Excel for iOS.

Side Note: The original Stack Overflow post has a successful answer with a dead link, here is a new link for reference: https://tzamtzis.gr/2017/web-analytics/excel-function-md5-hashing-without-vba/

Comment: Seriously, start a bounty.. get the original coder.. or an intern. ( :   |  Implementing an encryption algorithm is not easy yet it is not impossible. Since you'd mentioned avoiding 'broken' hashes is important, I think that easily rule out SHA256 & SHA512 . | IMHO: if your bussiness need this, it's worth developing it inhouse.

Comment: I could not more oppose the comment of @p-phidot. This does not help the OP in any way, is very rude in my opinion, and adds NOTHING to getting close to an answer to this valid question *whatsoever*. Please stop with these kinds of senseless and unhelpful comments.

Comment: I understand your point, thought I don’t see any sign of ‘some level of friendliness’  There might be more severe posts, but I’m not keeping tracking of a severity list, so I thought I’d respond to this one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've got one. Limits to 55 characters and designed more for educational purposes (i.e. how to see how SHA256 works in Excel....?).

To recap...

- No VBA.
- No named ranges.
- No arrays.
- Uses standard Excel functions found in 2007 and higher.
- Format is *.xlsx

[Download from OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gfx3sg_2Gues_u8mXA)

or

[Download from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17FsOyyr9RkwWj0Ug1tbyqJ5sSljGSjjg)

Comment: Thank you @PGSystemTester ! This is amazing, it even works on my iPhone! Sorry I took so long to thank you 

Comment: This method doesn't populate down a column as it's designed. How would that be done?

Comment: @mindmischief Google sheets has a script library for doing sha256 as an array which you could leverage as a custom function. From there, you could drag down a column of values. Sample file here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1alk5njX-ZK7jqWKqq9n9kGRmeXoP1O2dgWGYzbHf7fU/edit#gid=0  Note there are much better methods of doing this if you're trying to do some cracking of some kind.