# VBA: Automation error with "CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

Tags: vba

On Excel VBA, I got an automation error message when creating object `CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")`

Since it's a late binding call, I don't think it is related to a missing reference.
How to solve this error?

Comment: What error? ActiveX cannot create object?

Comment: I know this probably isn't in your real code but what's with the `"` at the start of the codeline?

Comment: It gives runtime error '-2146232576 (80131700)': Automation error.

Full line code: `Set web_Crypto = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")` 

Actually it's WebHelpers.HMACSHA1 function written by Tim Hall.

The prefix " was a typo.

Comment: That is because you are missing the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout
Problem solved once .Net Framework 3.5 is installed.
Stackoverflow also associates my question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988123/error-in-hash-implementation-in-vba-runtime-error-2146232576-80131700) which also has the same valid answer.

Comment: That association was "created" by *me* when I closed this quesiton as a duplicate :D

Comment: Ah,, Thanks again.