# Why am I receiving #VALUE! error using BASE64SHA1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a hash of a string using the UDF [BASE64SHA1.](https://gist.github.com/tomschenkjr/d6b28f98dec2f91f542a)

```
Public Function BASE64SHA1(ByVal sTextToHash As String)

    Dim asc As Object
    Dim enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Const cutoff As Integer = 5

    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

    TextToHash = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
    SharedSecretKey = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey

    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    BASE64SHA1 = EncodeBase64(bytes)
    BASE64SHA1 = Left(BASE64SHA1, cutoff)

    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing

End Function

Private Function EncodeBase64(ByRef arrData() As Byte) As String

    Dim objXML As Object
    Dim objNode As Object

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.text

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

End Function
```

When I execute the function, however, I receive a #VALUE! error. When I execute a [simpler UDF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f), it executes properly.

The only similar problem I was able to find online is from [mrexcel.com](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/code-not-running-on-new-computer.1082764/), but the problem wasn't resolved.

I am using a Microsoft Excel 365 for Mac v16.56. My macros are enabled. What am I missing?

Comment: Is MSXML2 available on Mac? I don't think so.

Comment: Added the code for the UDF under the link.

Comment: Just put `? BASE64SHA1(Sheet1.Range("A2").Value)` in the Immediate Window and hit Enter.

Comment: From the SO FAQ: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: @BigBen The output is `Run-time error 429: ActiveX component can't create object` and the Debug points to`Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")`

Comment: @BigBen Googling the Debug error points me to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988123/error-in-hash-implementation-in-vba-runtime-error-2146232576-80131700). I'm not able to understand all of it, but is the solution to download and install [Microsoft .NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) ?

Comment: I'm unable to help further (don't have a Mac to test on). But my hunch would be that this would need a significant rewrite to work on Mac. Could be wrong.