# Automation Error on some machines but not others

Tags: .net, excel, vba, runtime

I'm having an issue with a function I found here.  The idea is to create a hash from a string for use in a database.  The code runs fine on my machine as well as several of my co-workers.  There is one machine that throws an automation error when trying to execute it.  I've verified all of the references are the same, Excel and Office versions are the same.  Not sure what the issue is.

The function is called as part of a user form event and the code is as follows:

```
Public Function BASE64SHA1(ByVal sTextToHash As String)

    Dim asc As Object
    Dim enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Const cutoff As Integer = 28

    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

    TextToHash = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
    SharedSecretKey = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey

    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    BASE64SHA1 = EncodeBase64(bytes)
    BASE64SHA1 = Left(BASE64SHA1, cutoff)

    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing

End Function
```

```
Private Function EncodeBase64(ByRef arrData() As Byte) As String

    Dim objXML As Object
    Dim objNode As Object

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

End Function
```

Error occurs on this line:

`Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")`

Attempting to execute this line generates runtime error '-2146232576 (80131700)' Automation Error

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have dotNet framework installed ?

Comment: Per @CDP1802 You can either check the Registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT where you should find "System.Text.UTF8Encoding" listed, or check for the presence of the dll that provides the functionality: `C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll`

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  It was missing .NET 3.5 and I was able to solve the issue with instructions found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988123/error-in-hash-implementation-in-vba-runtime-error-2146232576-80131700